# Updating Symfony 2 fails with error due to symfony/finder

Tags: symfony, composer-php

Performed a standard installation of Symfony and attempted to update using `composer update` which gives the following error:

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
 - symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.9 requires symfony/finder ~2.0,>=2.0.5 -> no matching package found.
 - symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.8 requires symfony/finder ~2.0,>=2.0.5 -> no matching package found.
 - symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.10 requires symfony/finder ~2.0,>=2.0.5 -> no matching package found.
 - symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.38 requires symfony/finder ~2.0,>=2.0.5 -> no matching package found.
 - symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.37 requires symfony/finder ~2.0,>=2.0.5 -> no matching package found.
 - symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.36 requires symfony/finder ~2.0,>=2.0.5 -> no matching package found.
 - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.0.3
 - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.3
```

I am unable to add any further libraries as the standard update already fails. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "composer depends symfony/finder" will show you all packages that depend on symfony/finder. One of them must be blocking the update. I can't reproduce your issue by creating a new project with the Symfony installer and then updating dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your bug - update works ok on fresh symfony-standard project

This is result of `composer update` just after calling `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition`

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing monolog/monolog (1.17.2)
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.18.0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing paragonie/random_compat (v1.2.0)
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v1.2.1)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/monolog-bundle (v2.8.2)
  - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v2.9.0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v3.0.13)
  - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v3.0.14)
    Downloading: 100%

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

What You can do?

Try to clear your composer cache

```
composer clear-cache
```